# Use pushNamed with Dismissible Widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a Dismissible widget but I want to have the router history, I mean when I go to another route using the onDismissed event, when user presses back button on that new view be return to the first one.

This is my widget.

```
Dismissible(
  key: new ValueKey("dismiss_key"),
  direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
  child: Container(child: this.getTopPlacesSubscription()),
  onDismissed: (direction) {
    if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Router.getRoute(Routes.map));
    }
    if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushNamed(Router.getRoute(Routes.camera));
    }
  }
```

I will appreciate any help.
I got an issue trying to do it in this way.

Comment: Do you get an error screen when you go back?

Comment: Yeah, I meant that, I got an error screen when I go back, it indicates that I have to remove the widget from the application, but I need to have it there, I'm looking for a way to do that.

Comment: So basically you want a Dismissable widget for swiping left/right, your left view is camera and right view is a map, and you have kinda list of places in the middle view. Why don't you use TabBarView ?

Comment: I could implement it, I mean that will be my last decision, I am not a really lover of TabBarView, I prefer to use the Swipe, but I don't know if there is a way to do that, or if i will have to implement TabBarView .

Comment: I think I found a solution

Comment: Did you check the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code block will let you create a random string based on length. Add this to your code.

```
import 'dart:math';

String _randomString(int length) {
   var rand = new Random();
   var codeUnits = new List.generate(
      length, 
      (index){
         return rand.nextInt(33)+89;
      }
   );

   return new String.fromCharCodes(codeUnits);
}
```

In your state, define a new variable and give it a random value.

```
String vk;

@override
void initState() {
  this.vk =  _randomString(10)
}
```

Then go to your Dismissable widget and replace `vk` with your string. And here comes the magic part lol. You have to change your `vk` value in `onDismissed`. This will pass a new value to Dismissable key, so Flutter will recognize it as a new Widget, which will prevent the error.

```
Dismissible(
  key: new ValueKey(vk),
  direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
  child: Container(child: this.getTopPlacesSubscription()),
  onDismissed: (direction) {
    setState(() {
      this.vk = _randomString(10);
    });
    if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Router.getRoute(Routes.map));
    }
    if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushNamed(Router.getRoute(Routes.camera));
    }
  }
```